# Google SEO Using Search Console

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search

I am writing my personal website but it is not showing on the search engine so that I search from different forums. After searching a lot from the internet I read this google search console. So I register my site then successfully after 8 hours my site is showing in google using "*site:personalwebsite.xyz*" but after 24 hours my site is missing as in 0 result return. Guy's I am only a novice programmer so please help me how to show my site in google. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Google usually shows only the best and the most used contents. Yours is not maybe matching with keywords or there is sites more succesfully than yours.

Google may also take your site as "spam site" and thats reason why it wont show